# foreach looping only displaying last value of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach

I'm binding my gridview with multiple datakeys. I'm trying to let these datakey value to be displayed on the textbox when a particular row of gridview is being selected. Therefore i tried the following method below.

I managed to store my database value into a string based on the column number. I'm using a foreach so as  to loop the entire gridview when a particular row is being selected. But i'm not very sure why does it only display the last value of my gridview ?

```
protected void GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GWCase.Rows)
        {
            string detail = GWCase.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
            string propertydetail = GWCase.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
            string suspectdetail = GWCase.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString();

            tbdetails.Text = detail;
            tbproperty.Text = propertydetail;
            tbsuspect.Text = suspectdetail;
        }
```

I cant really convert it into a proper for loop because i got the gridview row there as well. Basically, i'm trying to display out the different value of the different datakey based on the selected gridview row.

Comment: what do you really need?

Comment: let me edit my question. seems like it not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to figure out the answer.

```
protected void GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int idx = GWCase.SelectedIndex; //add this line in
  string detail = GWCase.DataKeys[idx].Values[0].ToString();
  string propertydetail = GWCase.DataKeys[idx].Values[1].ToString();
  string suspectdetail = GWCase.DataKeys[idx].Values[2].ToString();

  tbdetails.Text = detail;
  tbproperty.Text = propertydetail;
  tbsuspect.Text = suspectdetail;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I think you want value from the selected row only. While looping you are not checking if the row is selected or not. That is why it shows only the stuff from last row. Try following:

```
protected void GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    GridViewRow selectedRow = GWCase.SelectedRow;

    if(selectedRow == null) return;

    /*GET VALUES FROM selectedRow AND DISPLAY THEM*/
}
```

Comment: i added that above the foreach loop but it still return me my last row of data from the gridview.

Comment: and my selectedrow wont be null. all of them are filled with that. just that it only return me the last row of my data.

Comment: As mentioned, you aren't checking for the values of the `SelectedRow` in your `foreach` loop. Thus, each iteration through the loop updates those `.Text` properties, and what is finally displayed to you is the last value through the loop.

Comment: So may i ask how do i check the value based on the selected gridview?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot showed you in the answer. You don't need your `foreach`, just set a local variable `GridViewRow` to the `.SelectedRow` and use its index values to get the values you care about.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan please remove the `foreach` loop `GWCase.SelectedRow` will directly give you desired row.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question: *Basically, i'm trying to display out the different value of the different datakey based on the selected gridview row.*

To get the values from the selected row, Use `DataKeyNames` property of GridView. Make sure you have a selectbutton present using `AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"` OR adding a button and set its `CommandName` Property to "`Select`".

Set `DataKeyNames` property to the Primary Key of your table. This can also contain more than one fields.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Employees" runat="server" DataSourceID="sourceEmployees" 
DataKeyNames="EmployeeID">
```

In your `selectedIndexChanged` event, you can access the Value of this `PrimaryKey` column as well as other columns:

```
protected void gridEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int index = gridEmployees.SelectedIndex;

//retrieve the Primary Key field from the SelectedDataKey property. 
  int ID = (int)gridEmployees.SelectedDataKey.Values["EmployeeID"];

// Get other columns values 
string firstName = gridEmployees.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text; 
string lastName = gridEmployees.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text; 
lblRegion.Text = gridEmployees.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text;

}
```

One another way  you can directly determine the data key value of the first key field of the selected row is  by using the SelectedValue property

```
// Returns only the value of First DataKey Field
int ID = (int)gridEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString();
```